# How to get mutable references to two array elements at the same time?

Tags: rust

```
fn change(a: &mut i32, b: &mut i32) {
    let c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    change(&mut v[0], &mut v[1]);
}
```

When I compile the code above, it has the error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `v` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:9:32
  |
9 |         change(&mut v[0], &mut v[1]);
  |                     -          ^   - first borrow ends here
  |                     |          |
  |                     |          second mutable borrow occurs here
  |                     first mutable borrow occurs here
```

Why does the compiler prohibit it? `v[0]` and `v[1]` occupy different memory positions, so it's not dangerous to use these together. And what should I do if I come across this problem?

Comment: Note that in this case you can use [`<[T]>::swap()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap).

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can solve this with [`split_at_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut):

```
let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
let (a, b) = v.split_at_mut(1);   // Returns (&mut [1], &mut [2, 3])
change(&mut a[0], &mut b[0]);
```

There are uncountably many safe things to do that the compiler unfortunately does not recognize yet. `split_at_mut()` is just like that, a safe abstraction implemented with an `unsafe` block internally.

We can do that too, for this problem. The following is something I use in code where I need to separate all three cases anyway (I: Index out of bounds, II: Indices equal, III: Separate indices).

```
enum Pair<T> {
    Both(T, T),
    One(T),
    None,
}

fn index_twice<T>(slc: &mut [T], a: usize, b: usize) -> Pair<&mut T> {
    if a == b {
        slc.get_mut(a).map_or(Pair::None, Pair::One)
    } else {
        if a >= slc.len() || b >= slc.len() {
            Pair::None
        } else {
            // safe because a, b are in bounds and distinct
            unsafe {
                let ar = &mut *(slc.get_unchecked_mut(a) as *mut _);
                let br = &mut *(slc.get_unchecked_mut(b) as *mut _);
                Pair::Both(ar, br)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

Since Rust 1.26, pattern matching can be done on slices. You can use that as long as you don't have huge indices and your indices are known at compile-time.

```
fn change(a: &mut i32, b: &mut i32) {
    let c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}

fn main() {
    let mut arr = [5, 6, 7, 8];
    {
        let [ref mut a, _, ref mut b, ..] = arr;
        change(a, b);
    }
    assert_eq!(arr, [7, 6, 5, 8]);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't have to be at compile-time or huge-index limited now thanks to let-else - you can do this: `let [first, .., second] = &mut arr[first_idx..=second_idx] else { panic!("second index was not greater") };` (Or you could've done if-let or a match before let-else)

Answer (score 10):

The borrow rules of Rust need to be checked at compilation time, that is why something like mutably borrowing a part of a `Vec` is a very hard problem to solve (if not impossible), and why it is not possible with Rust.

Thus, when you do something like `&mut v[i]`, it will mutably borrow the entire vector.

Imagine I did something like

```
let guard = something(&mut v[i]);
do_something_else(&mut v[j]);
guard.do_job();
```

Here, I create an object `guard` that internally stores a mutable reference to `v[i]`, and will do something with it when I call `do_job()`.

In the meantime, I did something that changed `v[j]`. `guard` holds a mutable reference that is supposed to guarantee nothing else can modify `v[i]`. In this case, all is good, as long as `i` is different from `j`; if the two values are equal it is a huge violation of the borrow rules.

As the compiler cannot guarantee that `i != j`, it is thus forbidden.

This was a simple example, but similar cases are legions, and are why such access mutably borrows the whole container. Plus the fact that the compiler actually does not know enough about the internals of `Vec` to ensure that this operation is safe even if `i != j`.

---

In your precise case, you can have a look at the [`swap(..)` method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap) available on `Vec` that does the swap you are manually implementing.

On a more generic case, you'll probably need an other container. Possibilities are wrapping all the values of your `Vec` into a type with interior mutability, such as [`Cell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.Cell.html) or [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), or even using a completely different container, as @llogiq suggested in his answer with [`par-vec`](https://github.com/contain-rs/par-vec).

Answer (score 10):

On nightly, there is [`get_many_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get_many_mut):

```rust
#![feature(get_many_mut)]

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let [a, b] = v
        .get_many_mut([0, 1])
        .expect("out of bounds or overlapping indices");
    change(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The method [`[T]::iter_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter_mut) returns an iterator that can yield a mutable reference for each element in the slice. Other collections have an `iter_mut` method too. These methods often encapsulate unsafe code, but their interface is totally safe.

Here's a general purpose extension trait that adds a method on slices that returns mutable references to two distinct items by index:

```
pub trait SliceExt {
    type Item;

    fn get_two_mut(&mut self, index0: usize, index1: usize) -> (&mut Self::Item, &mut Self::Item);
}

impl<T> SliceExt for [T] {
    type Item = T;

    fn get_two_mut(&mut self, index0: usize, index1: usize) -> (&mut Self::Item, &mut Self::Item) {
        match index0.cmp(&index1) {
            Ordering::Less => {
                let mut iter = self.iter_mut();
                let item0 = iter.nth(index0).unwrap();
                let item1 = iter.nth(index1 - index0 - 1).unwrap();
                (item0, item1)
            }
            Ordering::Equal => panic!("[T]::get_two_mut(): received same index twice ({})", index0),
            Ordering::Greater => {
                let mut iter = self.iter_mut();
                let item1 = iter.nth(index1).unwrap();
                let item0 = iter.nth(index0 - index1 - 1).unwrap();
                (item0, item1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building up on the answer by [@bluss](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30075629/166921) you can use `split_at_mut()` to create a function that can turn mutable borrow of a vector into a vector of mutable borrows of vector elements:

```rust
    fn borrow_mut_elementwise<'a, T>(v:&'a mut Vec<T>) -> Vec<&'a mut T> {
        let mut result:Vec<&mut T> = Vec::new();
        let mut current: &mut [T];
        let mut rest = &mut v[..];
        while rest.len() > 0 {
            (current, rest) = rest.split_at_mut(1);
            result.push(&mut current[0]);
        }
        result
    }
```

Then you can use it to get a binding that lets you mutate many items of original Vec at once, even while you are iterating over them (if you access them by index in your loop, not through any iterator):

```rust
    let mut items = vec![1,2,3];
    let mut items_mut = borrow_mut_elementwise(&mut items);
    for i in 1..items_mut.len() {
        *items_mut[i-1] = *items_mut[i];
    }
    println!("{:?}", items); // [2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `&mut v[…]` first mutably borrows `v` and then gives the mutable reference to the element to the change-function.

[This](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/34d42c/mutable_slice_chunking_problem/cqtndbz) reddit comment has a solution to your problem.

Edit: Thanks for the heads-up, Shepmaster. [par-vec](https://github.com/contain-rs/par-vec) is a library that allows to mutably borrow disjunct partitions of a vec.

Comment: Please inline the solution. Links go stale over time.

Answer (score 0):

I publish my daily utils for this to crate.io. [Link to the doc](https://docs.rs/arref).

You may use it like

```rust
use arref::array_mut_ref;
let mut arr = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
let (a, b) = array_mut_ref!(&mut arr, [1, 2]);
assert_eq!(*a, 2);
assert_eq!(*b, 3);
let (a, b, c) = array_mut_ref!(&mut arr, [1, 2, 0]);
assert_eq!(*c, 1);

// ⚠️ The following code will panic. Because we borrow the same element twice.
// let (a, b) = array_mut_ref!(&mut arr, [1, 1]);
```

It's a simple wrapper around the following code, which is sound. But it requires that the two indexes are different at runtime.

```rust
pub fn array_mut_ref<T>(arr: &mut [T], a0: usize, a1: usize) -> (&mut T, &mut T) {
    assert!(a0 != a1);
    // SAFETY: this is safe because we know a0 != a1
    unsafe {
        (
            &mut *(&mut arr[a0] as *mut _),
            &mut *(&mut arr[a1] as *mut _),
        )
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may use a method that won't panic with `mut_twice`

```rust
#[inline]
pub fn mut_twice<T>(arr: &mut [T], a0: usize, a1: usize) -> Result<(&mut T, &mut T), &mut T> {
    if a0 == a1 {
        Err(&mut arr[a0])
    } else {
        unsafe {
            Ok((
                &mut *(&mut arr[a0] as *mut _),
                &mut *(&mut arr[a1] as *mut _),
            ))
        }
    }
}
```