# Why I got "cannot borrow `arr[_]` as mutable more than once at a time"?

Tags: rust, swap, mutable, borrow

I have a programming assignment of creating a bubble sort using Rust. I don't really have much experience in Rust so this is a little bit hard for me:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Sort numbers ascending");
    let num:[i32; 10] = [4, 65, 2, -31, 0, 99, 2, 83, 782, 1];
    println!("Before: {:?}", num);
    bubble_sort( num);
    println!("After: {:?}\n", num);
}

fn swap( a: &mut i32, b: &mut i32){
    let tmp: i32 = *b;
    *b=*a;
    *a=tmp;
}

fn bubble_sort(mut arr: [i32; 10]) {
    for i in 0..arr.len() {
        for j in 0..arr.len() - 1 - i {
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1] {
                swap( &mut arr[j], &mut arr[j + 1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `arr[_]` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:19:24
   |
19 |                 swap( &mut arr[j], &mut arr[j + 1]);
   |                 ----  -----------  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                 |     |
   |                 |     first mutable borrow occurs here
   |                 first borrow later used by call
   |
   = help: consider using `.split_at_mut(position)` or similar method to obtain two mutable non-overlapping sub-slices

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get mutable references to two array elements at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073684/how-to-get-mutable-references-to-two-array-elements-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rust borrow checker is quite sophisticated, but it has limitations. Here, even though it's obvious to a human that there is no mutable aliasing going on, that fact is totally hidden from the borrow checker. It sees `&mut arr[j]` and `&mut arr[j + 1]` and concludes: "you're trying to borrow mutably from `arr` twice".

The error message does indicate the solution:

[`split_at_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut) is provided for exactly this situation. Under the hood, it uses `unsafe` to bend the above rule in a way that is still sound and will not cause UB. It takes an index to split at, and returns 2 non-overlapping mutable slices. This is the example from the docs:

```rust
let mut v = [1, 0, 3, 0, 5, 6];
let (left, right) = v.split_at_mut(2);
assert_eq!(left, [1, 0]);
assert_eq!(right, [3, 0, 5, 6]);
```

So in your case, instead of using `&mut arr[j]` to get a mutable reference to the number, you can do:

```
let (start, end) = arr.split_at_mut(1);
swap(&mut start[0], &mut end[0]);
```

P.S. there's also [`.swap(i, j)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap) for slices :-D