# Embedded rust - split large array/buffer in several smaller

Tags: rust, unsafe

I am quite a beginner in both rust and embedded programming in general. I have a rust datastructure which needs several (order 5) working buffers - `[f32; N]` in order to perform it's job. My inital plan was to wrap a large buffer in a struct - and then hand out mutable slices from that struct during initialization. The current `BufferManager` looks like this:

```rust
pub struct BufferManager<'a, const N: usize> {
    global_buffer : &'a mut [f32; N],
    offset: usize,
}

impl<'a, const N: usize> BufferManager<'a, N> {
    pub fn new(global_buffer: &'a mut [f32; N]) -> BufferManager<'a, N>{
        BufferManager{
            global_buffer,
            offset: 0,
        }
    }

    pub fn get_buffer(&mut self, size: usize) -> &mut [f32] {
        assert!(self.offset + size <= N);
        self.offset += size;
        unsafe{ self.global_buffer.get_unchecked_mut(self.offset-size..self.offset) }
    }
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_create_bm() {
        let mut global_buffer : [f32; 1024] = [0.0; 1024];
        let mut buffer_manager = BufferManager::<1024>::new(&mut global_buffer);

        let mut b1 = unsafe{ buffer_manager.get_buffer(512) };
        let mut b2 = unsafe{ buffer_manager.get_buffer(512) }; <---- Compiler error here

        b1[0] = 1.0;
        b2[0] = 1.0;

        //// Guaranteed aliasing!
        assert_eq!(global_buffer[0]  , 1.0);
        assert_eq!(global_buffer[512], 1.0);
    }
}
```

The current code will not compile - because there are multiple mutable borrows of the `buffer_manager` variable; I agree in that statement - but was maybe hoping the `unsafe` keyword would give me some magical powers to bypass the borrow checker.

Anyway - any suggestion on how to achieve this; or something roughly similar?

Comment: You either have to take all mutable borrows at the same time (See [How to get mutable references to two array elements at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30073684/how-to-get-mutable-references-to-two-array-elements-at-the-same-time)) or drop the parts of the slice that you've already handed out a reference to.

Comment: [Example of removing the part that is already returned](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fc8625a2d6ac042a3f678df760ca51a5)

Comment: OK - I see that it would be possible; although very un-ergonomic; to take all buffers at the same time. How would I go about to drop the parts which have already been handed out?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the working example! If you make it into a short answer I will Accept that right away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can realize your current api by only storing the parts of the `global_buffer` you have not returned yet:

```rust
pub struct BufferManager<'a> {
    global_buffer : &'a mut [f32],
}

impl<'a> BufferManager<'a> {
    pub fn new(global_buffer: &'a mut [f32]) -> BufferManager<'a>{
        BufferManager{
            global_buffer,
        }
    }

    pub fn get_buffer(&mut self, size: usize) -> &'a mut [f32] {
        assert!(size <= self.global_buffer.len());
        let head;
        (head, self.global_buffer) = std::mem::take(&mut self.global_buffer).split_at_mut(size);
        head
    }
}


#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_create_bm() {
        let mut global_buffer : [f32; 1024] = [0.0; 1024];
        let mut buffer_manager = BufferManager::new(&mut global_buffer);

        let mut b1 = buffer_manager.get_buffer(512);
        let mut b2 = buffer_manager.get_buffer(512);

        b1[0] = 1.0;
        b2[0] = 1.0;
        dbg!(global_buffer[0]);
        dbg!(global_buffer[512]);
    }
}
```

The previously explicitly stored `offset` is now implicit in the rest of the slice that is stored.

Comment: This works great. Just a minor comment: it is possible to use `core::mem::take()` instead - that is an important point for me because I need to use this code in a `[no_std]` context.